# Wp-less-cache issue changing CSS

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm making a web with a Wordpress and modifying some things with a child and css theme. The problem is that the theme uses a folder with the name "Wp-less-Cache" and inside it introduces a "theme-less.css" that it generates automatically. The problem is that now when I try to modify something by css the my mytheme.css (in the child) does not leave me because it tells me that what I want to retouch belongs to the file "theme-less.css" .... and if I tweak the CSS directly in that, it works but when this file is generated again automatically after a while it deletes the modifications that I had made in it.
I would like to know:
Can you disable the wp-less-cache? it is not in my list of plugins or among the plugin folders ...
Can I do something so that my modifications of the child theme are effective if he is active?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

It is used by one plugin called tlg_framework which is a built in plugin with themes that developed by http://www.themelogi.com/